# Uncaught TypeError: $.confirm is not a function con Socket

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, websocket

Estoy haciendo un sistema de turnos con en `php` nativo en el cual estoy usando una `librería` que se llama `fancywebsocket` en la cual desde la parte de donde se agenda la cita funciona bien, ya que luego que se guarda, muestra una alerta con la librería de `$.confirm` **"cita asignada"** hasta aquí bien, pero el otro lado en donde debe aparece la cita tambien pretendo mostrar una de las mismas alertas **"Tienes una nueva cita"** pero es aquí donde no me reconoce la librería y dicha función.

anexo las librerias usadas y el **codigo** de la funcion:

```
<!-- libreria del servidor socket -->
  <script src='../../functions/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
  <script src="../../functions/fancywebsocket.js"></script>

  <!-- Este SCRIPT ejecuta todos los alerts -->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../cx/demo/libs/bundled.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../cx/demo/demo.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../cx/jquery-confirm.css'>
  <script src='../../cx/demo/libs/bundled.js'></script>
  <script src='../../cx/demo/demo.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../../cx/jquery-confirm.js'></script>


  <!-- Despliega otra ventana de dialogo interna -->
  <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="../colorbox/colorbox/colorbox.css" />
  <script src='../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src="../colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

**Funcion** desde el primer lado funciona perfectamente, no se si alguna libreria este interfiriendo con ello.

```
 $.confirm({
              icon: 'fa fa-user-circle-o',
              theme: 'supervan',
              closeIcon: false,
              content: 'TIENES UNA NUEVA CITA!',
              animation: 'scale',
              type: 'green',
              buttons: {
                  'ok': {
                      text: 'OK',
                      btnClass: 'btn-blue',
                      action: function () {
                      }
                  },
              }
          });
```

Si necesitan codigo del socket me avisan:

De antemano muchisimas gracias...

Comment: ese error quizás sea por el orden de tus js y no alcanza a reconocer la librería cuando ejecutas el código, como se llama el archivo donde ejecutas $.confirm.

Comment: entonces como deberia ordenarlos ? ademas en el otro archivo los tengo el mismo orden y si funciona

Comment: como se llama el archivo donde tienes el codigo de $.confirm({...})

Comment: se llama `should.php` tambien lo tengo en `quotes.php` y el intermedioario es `fancy.php`

Comment: pero no es un archivo JS?

Comment: por que llamas dos veces jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: Si brother, con tu primer comentario lo note, muchas gracias bro... ahi publique respues, para las futuras generaciones... graicas

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado el error...

```
<!-- libreria del servidor socket -->

//aqui tengo el jquery de la websocket

<script src='../../functions/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
  <script src="../../functions/fancywebsocket.js"></script>

  <!-- Este SCRIPT ejecuta todos los alerts -->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../cx/demo/libs/bundled.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../cx/demo/demo.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../cx/jquery-confirm.css'>
  <script src='../../cx/demo/libs/bundled.js'></script>
  <script src='../../cx/demo/demo.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../../cx/jquery-confirm.js'></script>


  <!-- Despliega otra ventana de dialogo interna -->
  <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="../colorbox/colorbox/colorbox.css" />

//y aqui tenia el mismo jquery de la otra libreria
  <script src='../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src="../colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

Lo que sucedia era que le lo leia la primera ves y si lo reconocia, pero luego lo volvia a leer y ya no era alcanzable, entonces quedo asi:

```
  <!-- libreria del servidor socket -->
  <script src='../../functions/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
  <script src="../../functions/fancywebsocket.js"></script>

  <!-- Despliega otra ventana de dialogo interna -->
  <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="../colorbox/colorbox/colorbox.css" />
  <!-- <script src='../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->
  <script src="../colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

  <!-- Este SCRIPT ejecuta todos los alerts -->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../cx/demo/libs/bundled.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../cx/demo/demo.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../cx/jquery-confirm.css'>
  <script src='../../cx/demo/libs/bundled.js'></script>
  <script src='../../cx/demo/demo.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../../cx/jquery-confirm.js'></script>
```

**Quizas esto sirva para futuros programadores en Busca de errores. Aveces solo depende del orden y liena de ejecusion de las librerias**

Agradecimientos a @TheVicious su opinion me ayudo mucho a resolverlo

Comment: Excelente que te halla servido mis comentarios, en SOes siempre estamos para poder brindar mejores soluciones a diferentes problemáticas.

Comment: Si, aveces un punto de vista diferente hace la diferencia..... de nuevo gracias